# share a ng-bootstrap modal across views

Tags: angular, bootstrap-modal, ng-bootstrap

In my component's template, I am using this ng bootstrap `ngbModalContainer` attribute

```
<template ngbModalContainer></template>
```

I open the modal like this

```
this.modalService.open(componentForMyModal);
```

How can I have the modal persist on the screen when I change views ?

Comment: You should just need to open this in the component that the changing views are rendered within - ie the view which has the router output tag.

Comment: if I move ngModalContainer directive to my mainComponent.html, where the router outlet is, it won't be reachable by modalService from a sub component

Comment: Please provide a plunker to reproduce your problem

Answer (score 0):

In angular 2 when using a router there is a central point from where you load the routes normally inside your main app.component.html file

```
 <router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

if you want to share html and / or component with all the routes you would do it here either below or above the router-outlet tag.
so if you want to have a navbar shared between all components all you would do in the app.component.html is:

```
  <nav> </nav>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Comment: For clarification you would have your opening modal code inside the app.component.ts file and it will be shared across all of the routes